# Статические поля класса при наследовании

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть абстрактный класс Figure и производные от него Triangle и Rectangle.

```
class Figure {
public:
    Figure(std::vector<Point2D>& array) {
        _array = new Point2D[vertices];
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices; ++i) {
            _array[i] = array[i];
        }
    }

...

protected:
    static std::string name; // name - имя фигуры (треугольник, прямоугольник)
    static int vertices; // количество вершин у фигуры
    Point2D* _array; // массив точек, задающих фигуру
};
```

Мне бы хотелось использовать конструктор класса **Figure** и в дочерних классах, а также хотелось бы хранить информацию о классах в статических переменных. Так как очевидно, что количество вершин у всех прямоугольников равно четырем, а у треугольника это количество другое.

Однако конструктор всех фигур имеет одинаковый вид - по вектору точек заполняем внутренний массив. Как реализовать эту идею? Очевидно, сейчас код работать не будет, так как при вызове конструктора **Figure** он будет обращаться к своей статической переменной **vertices**, а не к количеству вершин, например, прямоугольника.

Comment: Это не тот случай, когда нужно использовать статические члены. На входе в конструктор у вас вектор, а вектор знает своё количество элементов. Замените массив вершин на вектор - и тогда дополнительный член для количества вообще не будет нужен.

Comment: @maestro, предположим, что мне все же необходимо хранить именно массив

Comment: Не помню точно, но вроде бы для наследников переопределить статическую переменную не получится. Можно использовать обычный член и инициализировать его в конструкторе исходя из размера вектора.

Comment: При вызове конструктора базового класса дочернего тела объекта ещё не существует *он ещё не инициализирован*. Чтобы была инициализация виртуальная в зависимости от типа, можно сначала создать объект с помощью инициализации по-умолчанию. Потом задавать вектора виртуальной функцией `virtual int Vertices()`.

Comment: *"предположим, что мне все же необходимо хранить именно массив"* Почему? Вы понимаете, что из вектора можно достать указатель на первый элемент, и делать с ним все то же, что и с массивом? Я понимаю, когда студентам вообще запрещают использовать контейнеры, но тогда его бы и в параметре функции не было.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, понимаю, но  проблема скорее не в выборе вектора или массива, поскольку количество вершин мне бы все равно хотелось хранить как статический член в каждом классе. Поскольку, кроме прочего, мне нужно еще реализовать валидацию переданных точек, а она начинается как раз-таки с проверки соответствия количества переданных точек с нужным количеством.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хранение информации о классах в статических переменных - вполне здравая идея. Однако размещая статическое поле в базовом классе оно будет одно на все экземпляры этого класса; входящие и в объекты `Triangle`, и в объекты `Rectangle`. Вместо этого поле следует размещать в самих дочерних классах. Хотя сами поля статические, но доступ к ним из базового класса можно будет получить только посредством динамической диспетчеризации, через виртуальные методы, ведь в базовом классе заранее не известно, подобъектом объекта какого из дочерних классов тот является. Однако это влечет другую проблему - вызов виртуальных методов нельзя производить внутри конструкторов и деструкторов. А значит, что передавать в конструктор базового класса размер необходимо явно.

В итоге, после правок получается что-то подобное:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

using
Points = ::std::vector<Point2D>;

class Figure
{
    private: Points m_points;

    protected: explicit
    Figure(Points const & points, ::std::size_t const points_count)
    :   m_points{points.data(), points.data() + points_count}
    {}
 
    public: virtual ::std::string_view
    Fetch_Name(void) const noexcept = 0;
 
    public: virtual ::std::size_t
    Fetch_PointsCount(void) const noexcept = 0;

    ...
};

class Triangle final
:   public Figure
{
    private: static constexpr ::std::string_view const s_name{"Triangle"};
    private: static constexpr ::std::size_t const s_points_count{3};

    public: explicit
    Triangle(Points const & points)
    :   Figure{points, s_points_count}
    {}
 
    public: ::std::string_view
    Fetch_Name(void) const noexcept override
    { return s_name; }
 
    public: ::std::size_t
    Fetch_PointsCount(void) const noexcept override
    { return s_points_count; }
};

class Rectangle final
:   public Figure
{
    private: static constexpr ::std::string_view const s_name{"Rectangle"};
    private: static constexpr ::std::size_t const s_points_count{4};

    public: explicit
    Rectangle(Points const & points)
    :   Figure{points, s_points_count}
    {}
 
    public: ::std::string_view
    Fetch_Name(void) const noexcept override
    { return s_name; }
 
    public: ::std::size_t
    Fetch_PointsCount(void) const noexcept override
    { return s_points_count; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Сюда напрашивается что-то вроде этого:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

struct Point2D {float x = 0, y = 0;};

class BasicShape
{
  public:
    virtual ~BasicShape() = default;

    virtual std::span<Point2D> GetPoints() = 0;

    std::span<const Point2D> GetPoints() const
    {
        return const_cast<BasicShape &>(*this).GetPoints();
    }

    // ...
};

template <std::size_t N>
class Shape : public BasicShape
{
    Point2D points[N]{};

  public:
    Shape() {}
    Shape(std::span<const Point2D, N> span)
    {
        std::ranges::copy(span, points);
    }

    std::span<Point2D> GetPoints() override {return points;}
    using BasicShape::GetPoints;
};

class Triangle : public Shape<3>
{
  public:
    using Shape::Shape;
};

class Square : public Shape<4>
{
  public:
    using Shape::Shape;
};

int main()
{
    // Подбором определил, сколько должно быть пар скобочек. :)
    Triangle tri = {{{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}}};

    for (Point2D point : tri.GetPoints())
        std::cout << point.x << ' ' << point.y << '\n';
}
```

Массив на куче не храним, чтобы быстрее работало.

`BasicShape` и все виртуальные функции можно спокойно убрать, если полиморфизм не нужен, и сложить все общие методы в шаблон (в этой ситуации часто бывает нужен CRTP, но именно тут не нужен).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

struct Point2D {float x = 0, y = 0;};

template <std::size_t N>
class Shape
{
    Point2D points[N]{};

  public:
    Shape() {}
    Shape(std::span<const Point2D, N> span)
    {
        std::ranges::copy(span, points);
    }

    std::span<Point2D> GetPoints() {return points;}
    
    std::span<const Point2D> GetPoints() const
    {
        return const_cast<Shape &>(*this).GetPoints();
    }
};

class Triangle : public Shape<3>
{
  public:
    using Shape::Shape;
};

class Square : public Shape<4>
{
  public:
    using Shape::Shape;
};

int main()
{
    // Подбором определил, сколько должно быть пар скобочек. :)
    Triangle tri = {{{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}}};

    for (Point2D point : tri.GetPoints())
        std::cout << point.x << ' ' << point.y << '\n';
}
```